# HStore is saved but rolls back after reload [Rails 4.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

Im using postgres and using HSTORE

In User model
    store_accessor :filter_options, :makes, :cities, :bodies, :detail_types, :engines, :transmissions

then I do
    self.filter_options = new_options

```
self.save
```

=> true

> > self.filter_options
> >     => {"makes"=>"[2]", "cities"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]", "bodies"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]", "engines"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]", "detail_types"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]", "transmissions"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"}

As we see it is stored correctly, but if I refresh the page or do **self.reload**, it is rolled back

> > self.reload.filter_options
> >     => {"makes"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111]", "cities"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]", "bodies"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]", "engines"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]", "detail_types"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]", "transmissions"=>"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]"}

Comment: Have you tried manually marking the field as dirty? Try `filter_options_will_change!` before setting the field. You should check the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) docs. Are you overriding the `filter_options=` setter method? Do you have any [Rails Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) that might be rolling the data back?

Comment: Even if all callbacks are disabled:
 SQL (5.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "filter_options" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["filter_options", "\"makes\"=>\"[2]\", \"cities\"=>\"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]\", \"bodies\"=>\"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]\", \"engines\"=>\"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]\", \"detail_types\"=>\"[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]\", \"transmissions\"=>\"[1, 3, 4, 5, 6]\""], ["updated_at", "2015-07-21 22:48:32.035497"], ["id", 5]]
   (9.3ms)  COMMIT

No overrides, filter_options_will_change! does not help

Comment: The main thing that other fields are saved properly, the problem is only with that HStore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rogue after_initialize callback has invaded my model, problem solved